# AWS Amplify failing to activate custom domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-cloudfront, aws-amplify

I created an Amplify application and linked my custom domain from Google domains. I linked it a few months ago and it deployed successfully- my website was live for few months.

Then I accidentally deleted the domain on Amplify console and had to redo the domain activation process. I went through the same process as I did it previously, but it now fails on `Domain Activation` step, saying

> Something went wrong. Please refer to our troubleshooting guide below
> to diagnose the issue. After fixing the issue, choose retry below.
>
> Error message: One or more aliases specified for the distribution
> includes an incorrectly configured DNS record that points to another
> CloudFront distribution. You must update the DNS record to correct the
> problem. For more information, see
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html#alternate-domain-names-restrictions

`SSL Creation` and `SSL Configuration` steps pass. I checked my Google domain DNS config, and everything seems correctly configured. I also checked [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/custom-domain-troubleshoot-guide.html) and verified that my CNAME resolves to the correct URL and also deleted all distributions on CloudFront so I can start fresh... but still getting the same error. Appreciate any help from you ops experts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a correct fix to the issue, but I ended up

1. deleting the domain and setting it up again, except I added another subdomain `www` in the amplify console and made it point to main github branch. So on Amplify's domain management console, I would start with `https://your-website.com` and `https://www.your-website.com` pointing to main branch (+ more subdomains as needed).
2. added necessary CNAME records on google domains

Took a few minutes to propagate and it's live again!